# change toggle menu-bar activation key

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use i3 window manager on Linux which has already `Alt` as keybinding for actions and have as keyboard-centric user no use for menu-bars. Therefor I would like to know how to change the keybinding to hide the menu-bar in Visual Studio Code – so that it isn't activated by "accident" all time when running i3-actions.

Changing the keybinding settings to `{ "key": "alt", "command": "-workbench.action.toggleMenuBar"}` has no effect. Also binding toggleMenuBar to another key works, but doesn't remove the existing `Alt` binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest releases should have option in the `User Settings` file.

I tested it in `Version 1.16.1`.

```
"window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden",
```

Set it to `hidden` as above. This will disable the toggling of menu using <kbd>alt</kbd> key.

You may want to bind the toggling to other key in `keybindings.json` file:

```
{
    "key": "f10",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMenuBar"
}
```

Here I have bind it to <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: You're a savior :-)